# JTree Node Names / Group names are not visible

Tags: swing, jtree

I've written a JTree with couple of nodes. When I launch the program, I only see the node icons like folder or file and not the names associated with them. I could expand and collapse the nodes. When I debug, I see that the nodes are set with proper data whatever I used while building the model. In this program, i've written wrappers for JTree, TreeModel, DefaultMutableTreeNode. What could be the problem? Any pointers would be of great help. 
-Paul

Comment: The problem is in the code, at line 576, or perhaps 362.

Comment: you should post a little bit code so we can help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not posting more details/code. Anyway, I've found the problem with my code. The problem was that I had overridden the toString() method in the class that I use to set as user object for the tree node, but that was returning null. As the method was returning null, there was nothing displayed. I made it to return the string to be displayed. It is working good now.
Thanks guys..!